# What is the good way to make a recursive list

Tags: r, list

Let's say, I have 3 numbers: `20,10,5` and `len=5`

I want to make a list of:

```
20
10
5
20 20
20 10
20 5
10 20
10 10
10 5
5 20
5 10
5 5
20 20 20
20 20 10
20 20 5
20 10 20
..
20 20 20 20 20
..
5 5 5 5 5
```

But I am not sure how to make this kind of list in a good way (whatever programming language, but R is prefer)?

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: figure out how to get lists of a certain length and concat-map over [1..len] - if you can figure out how to get all lists of length 1 and how to to go from n-1 to n then recursion might be handy ;)

Comment: See this >> http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/all-combinations-with-replacement-td3466696.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in Python:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

l = 5 #len is a reserved keyword in Python

for i in range(1, l+1):
    print(list(combinations_with_replacement([20, 10, 5], i)))
```

Result

`[(20,), (10,), (5,)]
 [(20, 20), (20, 10), (20, 5), (10, 10), (10, 5), (5, 5)]
 [(20, 20, 20), (20, 20, 10), (20, 20, 5), (20, 10, 10), (20, 10, 5)`

I cut the output short due to its length, but you get the idea.

Comment: @mamatv  This works, but I don't think it should be the accepted answer since it isn't written in the requested language.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
x <- c(20, 10, 5)
len <- 5
rl <- sapply(1:len, function(n) expand.grid(list(x)[rep(1, n)]))
```

Here `rl` is a list of length `len`, where, e.g.,

```
rl[[2]]
#   Var1 Var2
# 1   20   20
# 2   10   20
# 3    5   20
# 4   20   10
# 5   10   10
# 6    5   10
# 7   20    5
# 8   10    5
# 9    5    5
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an answer for R:

```
library (gtools)
permutations (n = length (c(20,10,5)), r = 5, v = c(20,10,5), repeats.allowed=TRUE)
```

Comment: Did you run this?  It returns an error.  For what OP wants it would be something like `x <- c(20, 10, 5); lapply(1:5, function(i) permutations(length(x), i, x, repeats = TRUE))`

Comment: Yeah, I ran it and have no problem. What error do you have?

Comment: Well of course now it works since you edited it.  But OP doesn't want just r = 5, he wants r = 1, 2, ..., 5

Comment: Yeah, in this case use lapply as you did and I think it is correct. Btw I am the asking person :-). Thank you very much

Comment: Oh, oops I didn't see that you are the OP.  Sorry.  You should probably clarify then because this is not the same as what you show as your desired result in the question.

Comment: No problem, your solution is indeed a great one.